# Does frequently editing questions with proper reason lead to suspension?

Tags: discussion, edits

Is editing questions with proper reason wrong?

If a user asks a question,  after asking the user will still be working on the questions issue.

After asking, the user may feel the question needs to be edited:

1. with proper tags
2. removing unwanted code or adding required code

If the issue is very difficult and the user is a beginner level coder, the user may have added wrong code, later the user edits the question with the correct code. The user may frequently edit the questions more times.

Is this behaviour wrong?

**Edit**

If it is wrong, the system should be in such a way that the OP can edit the question only "n" number of times.....

Please review this [edit](https://magento.stackexchange.com/posts/165980/revisions) and tell me whether I did wrong in editing? Because my account got suspended for 2 months because of editing this question too much.

Comment: *Does frequently editing questions with proper reason lead to suspension?* No, because then I would've been suspended multiple times by now in sites I frequent. However, going on an editing spree, *and* invalidating answers each time would be enough reason to need to cool off in a corner for a while.

Comment: I don't think you're being entirely honest with everyone here. Moderators don't just jump to a two-month suspension for edit abuse, so there's more here than you're telling us. That string of votes you just received yesterday on Magento sure looks suspicious, for one: http://magento.stackexchange.com/users/12982/baby-in-magento?tab=reputation&sort=post . Is there anything you'd like to add?

Comment: @BradLarson Moderators really suspended just for editing my own posts and they send the same message, i really have no idea who did that much votes for me , why they did that and what they will get from that, please you can reverse all those serial votes, but please help me to remove suspension period.....

Comment: @user12345 Moderators aren't going to suspend you for making *appropriate* edits.  They sure will suspend people for making *inappropriate* edits.  If you were suspended, then the edits you were making weren't appropriate.

Comment: @Servy i really did't edit question without any wrong intention or for wrong reason, my intention was only to improve the posts , so that it will help community to understand what issue i am facing. from now onwards i decided not do edit any question once after i posted :(

Comment: @user12345 If you didn't edit a question inappropriately you wouldn't have been suspended *multiple* times for it.  You can't say that you didn't realize what you were doing was wrong considering you've been suspended for the behavior before (and I strongly suspect you've been warned before that) meaning you were *knowingly* performing inappropriate edits, not innocently performing inappropriate edits.

Comment: I have really huge respect on our community moderators : http://magento.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators , they are really doing very good job , if i did wrong edits, i completely respect their opinion as i deserved to be suspended, but i did't done any edits inappropriate edits here.....

Comment: @user12345 The one example you've provided shows you making *lots* of inappropriate edits (on just that one question alone).  Clearly the suspension is entirely warranted.  That you think that those edits are appropriate, despite being *suspended for making edits like that before* means that you haven't learned from your mistakes and corrected your behavior, leaving moderators with a suspension as their only course of action.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

NO, it is not wrong, this thing happens with high rep users as well, editing is essential, if you see the edit history of highly voted answer, in most of the cases you will observe they are first written as a stub later on the op and other user adds the necessary details. Op can edit <del>multiple time regardless of frequency</del> if it is correcting or improving the post.

**Edit**: User have five edits per day on their own post, limit for high rep user depends on their rep, mods are exempted. As described in this [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide/164900#164900) referred by @SLBarth.

Comment: Thanks, please check `edit` part in question.....

Comment: Your question now is changing over and over again, just like the one you referenced... We can't deal with suspensions here, so if you want to talk about that specific occassion, respond to the moderator message or discuss it on your site's meta.

Comment: You did very heavy editing and awarded bounty multiple times, It is suspicious for moderators in case you are transferring rep. but even if you are not it is still expected that your matter at hand should end with initial answers. if your question not fully answered, instead of editing existing question over and over you should ask new question. refer this [timeline](http://magento.stackexchange.com/posts/165980/timeline) of your question if you want to observe.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Hello, I think you want to say this to op, and also op might not able to ask on his site meta because of suspension.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Thanks for suggestion.....

Comment: @AbhishekGurjar i am really not doing this to transfer any bounty points , as i need to solve the issue, i opened bounty multiple times, still i didt got any solution for that, thanks for suggestion.....

Comment: "OP can edit multiple time regardless of frequency". A little nitpick: an OP can edit their post 5 times per day, more if their reputation is higher. See the [rate limiting guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164900/168333).

Comment: @S.L.Barth Thanks for reference, but my context was different does it apply for grace period too.

Comment: Why the downvotes? I wrote the answer at instance which is fulfilling the OP's query.

Comment: @AbhishekGurjar Because your answer is wrong.  Your answer to the question is wrong in saying that it's appropriate to radically change the code in someone else's question, it's wrong to say that most answers are edited to include additional information (this does happen, but it's a fairly small percent of answers, nowhere even *near* a majority, and of course there are all sorts of edits that aren't appropriate and that, if performed repeatedly, could result in a suspension.

Comment: @Servy I am not saying OP to change someone else's code **radically** nonetheless I am giving him the example what happens with even highly voted answers, that not every post is perfect at start.

Comment: @AbhishekGurjar The question was whether or not it's appropriate to radically change the code in the question.  You said it's not wrong, so you *did* in fact say it's okay to radically change the code in the question.  Saying that a very tiny number of answers get edited to be improved is both not at all what you said (again, you said *majority*) and is also simply irrelevant.  Adding additional supplementary information to an answer is fine; completely changing what a question is asking *isn't*.

Comment: @Servy With respect, still I can't find where I said in my answer to change the overall post by editing, I only mention the correct or improve the post regarding op's own post not the someone else's post, my example may be inappropriate but I further explain the op in comments that he did heavy editing which altered the op's original question.

Comment: @AbhishekGurjar The OP asked if it's appropriate for them to radically edit the question into a different question.  You said that it's not wrong, so that * and said nothing more on the subject (the rest of your answer is an incorrect and irrelevant statement).  Since the entirety of your answer was saying that it's not wrong, your answer *is* asserting that it's okay to radically change what a question is asking.

Answer (score 10):

Editing is an import part of how Q&A works on Stack Exchange and limiting the number edits certainly isn't a good idea.

As others have said, edits should improve the question, an important point though; edits should *never* change the meaning of the question. Editing broken code or swapping out a code block for a different piece of code sounds awfully a lot like it is changing the question. That shouldn't be done. It invalidates any existing answers (or even the work done on a yet unposted answer).

Comment: Thanks, yes thats right : `should never change the meaning of the question` , but i edited the question to make it more clear.....

Comment: You changed a bunch of code. That's not making things clearer, that's changing the question. But if you're worried about a specific edit, you should ask on that site's meta (in this case [Magento Meta](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/))

Comment: After posting question, i was working on the issue, so i deleted the old code added the code that will help to get solution....

Comment: As I said, that's not really what you should do. A Q&A should be a single focused answerable problem. You should more than likely have been posting more follow up question, linking to the first to give context

Comment: Yeah - editing questions to improve them is good as long it does not strand any answers provided in good faith to the question as it was when they were posted.

Answer (score 5):

While there is no fixed limit on how many edits you can make, and usually you can make as many edits to your posts as you want, there *is* a requirement to use common sense.

You made *eighteen* edits to that question, many of them minuscule.

It really, really looks like this was not done in good faith, but that you did it to bump the question to the front page continuously.

That's abusive behaviour and it's presumably what you got a suspension for.

The system doesn't need to address *every* possible form of misuse - the rare instances where that happens can be handled manually, as happened here.

Try to limit the frequency of your edits a bit. If you see a little thing that needs fixing, try to look for all the *other* things at the same time.

Comment: I did the edit not with intention to bring to front page, but to improve the question, also as i opened bounty for the question, there is no requirement to bring to the frontpage. i know that without asking good question ,how many times if we bring the question to front page, than its of no use..... Thanks for answer....

Comment: No problem. As said, the suspension probably had other reasons, too. Those should have been explained to you in the moderator message you received.

Comment: But just for editing the question without any wrong intention, i believe its completely injustice to suspend for period of 2 months....

Comment: but still as you said, when i am editing i will look at all the other parts of question..... also from now i decided i  am not going to edit any question at all.....

Comment: A lot of the edits were to add, remove or completely change big chunks of code, which is a bigger problem @Pëkka

Comment: @user12345 a good rule of thumb; if your question is about code... don't edit the code

Comment: @user12345 I do not believe you got the suspension only for this episode. I'm willing to bet there was more that you're not telling us.

Comment: @Cai yeah, true.

Comment: @Pëkka before, i  suspended for the one month period for same reason.....

Comment: @Cai thanks for suggestion.....

Answer (score 4):

Editing a question multiple times is not wrong **as long as it improves the question**.

If a edit merely adds one or two words to bump the question to the front page, I would say that is wrong. As long as the edit adds something useful, or removes something unnecessary, it is okay.

For your edit: no, the system should not automatically block edits after X times. We already have a mechanism in place to evaluate edits, and that is bumping it to the front page. Users will notice it quite quickly if an edit is okay or not.

Comment: Thanks, please check `edit` part in question.....

Comment: @user12345 - Your last edit changed the question significantly.  You have to talk to the moderator over at Magento SE if you want to be unbanned.  You abused the edit system, QED

Comment: @Ramhound I informed moderators i done edit not with any wrong intention, but just to improve question, if they revert to old edit , that should be fine, but its really hurt a lot when they suspended for this......

Comment: It will give you time to review our rules and absorb the reasons those edits were not justified that we shared with you.